# Python cookbook logging socket server client logger does not send packets

Tags: python

I'm using the recipe directly from [the cookbook](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html), with the exception of a single line {ctrl-f for "print(rd,"} printing whatever pumps out of the socket:

```
import pickle
import logging
import logging.handlers
import socketserver
import struct


class LogRecordStreamHandler(socketserver.StreamRequestHandler):
    """Handler for a streaming logging request.

    This basically logs the record using whatever logging policy is
    configured locally.
    """

    def handle(self):
        """
        Handle multiple requests - each expected to be a 4-byte length,
        followed by the LogRecord in pickle format. Logs the record
        according to whatever policy is configured locally.
        """
        while True:
            chunk = self.connection.recv(4)
            if len(chunk) < 4:
                break
            slen = struct.unpack('>L', chunk)[0]
            chunk = self.connection.recv(slen)
            while len(chunk) < slen:
                chunk = chunk + self.connection.recv(slen - len(chunk))
            obj = self.unPickle(chunk)
            record = logging.makeLogRecord(obj)
            self.handleLogRecord(record)

    def unPickle(self, data):
        return pickle.loads(data)

    def handleLogRecord(self, record):
        # if a name is specified, we use the named logger rather than the one
        # implied by the record.
        if self.server.logname is not None:
            name = self.server.logname
        else:
            name = record.name
        logger = logging.getLogger(name)
        # N.B. EVERY record gets logged. This is because Logger.handle
        # is normally called AFTER logger-level filtering. If you want
        # to do filtering, do it at the client end to save wasting
        # cycles and network bandwidth!
        logger.handle(record)

class LogRecordSocketReceiver(socketserver.ThreadingTCPServer):
    """
    Simple TCP socket-based logging receiver suitable for testing.
    """

    allow_reuse_address = True

    def __init__(self, host='localhost',
                 port=logging.handlers.DEFAULT_TCP_LOGGING_PORT,
                 handler=LogRecordStreamHandler):
        socketserver.ThreadingTCPServer.__init__(self, (host, port), handler)
        self.abort = 0
        self.timeout = 1
        self.logname = None

    def serve_until_stopped(self):
        import select
        abort = 0
        while not abort:
            rd, wr, ex = select.select([self.socket.fileno()],
                                       [], [],
                                       self.timeout)
            print(rd, wr, ex)
            if rd:
                self.handle_request()
            abort = self.abort

def main():
    logging.basicConfig(
        format='%(relativeCreated)5d %(name)-15s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
    tcpserver = LogRecordSocketReceiver()
    print('About to start TCP server...')
    tcpserver.serve_until_stopped()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

To test, I use the recipe directly from [the cookbook](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html):

```
import logging, logging.handlers

rootLogger = logging.getLogger('')
rootLogger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
socketHandler = logging.handlers.SocketHandler('localhost',
                    logging.handlers.DEFAULT_TCP_LOGGING_PORT)
# don't bother with a formatter, since a socket handler sends the event as
# an unformatted pickle
rootLogger.addHandler(socketHandler)

# Now, we can log to the root logger, or any other logger. First the root...
logging.info('Jackdaws love my big sphinx of quartz.')
```

But the thing just pumps out:

```
About to start TCP server...
[] [] []
[] [] []
[] [] []
[] [] []
....
```

Ad infinitum.

However, if I start up a basic socket client in another terminal:

```
import socket
import logging.handlers
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("localhost",logging.handlers.DEFAULT_TCP_LOGGING_PORT))
s.send('blah'.encode())
```

I get:

```
....
[] [] []
[] [] []
[] [] []
[3] [] []
[] [] []
....
```

So the error is in the `logging.handlers.SocketHandler`, but it doesn't give any errors or anything, it just doesn't work.

Any thoughts?

**UPDATE:**

This seemed like it might be helpful:

```
>>> socketHandler.__dict__
{'filters': [], '_name': None, 'level': 0, 'formatter': None, 'lock': <unlocked _thread.RLock object owner=0 count=0 at 0x7f6094d20330>, 'host': 'localhost', 'port': 9020, 'address': ('localhost', 9020), 'sock': None, 'closeOnError': False, 'retryTime': 1531926559.6880224, 'retryStart': 1.0, 'retryMax': 30.0, 'retryFactor': 2.0, 'retryPeriod': 8.0}
```

**UPDATE:**

It looks like it might be an IPV6 vs IPV4 problem.  Specifically, `SocketHandler.makeSocket()` calls `socket.create_connection`, which in turn calls `socket.getaddrinfo`.  On my machine, `socket.getaddrinfo` only returns IPV6 stuff, and coincidentally, `socket.create_connection` goes on to throw a `ConnectionRefused` error when it gets to the `.connect` call.

Answer (score 0):

Still only 85% sure this is an ipv6 vs ipv4 problem, but circumventing the call to `socket.create_connection` solves the problem for me.  Here's a clean way to do it:

```
from logging import *
import logging.handlers
import socket

class SocketHandler(logging.handlers.SocketHandler):
    def makeSocket(self, timeout=1):
        result = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        try:
            result.connect(self.address)
        except OSError:
            result.close()
            raise
        return result

rootLogger = getLogger('')
rootLogger.setLevel(DEBUG)
socketHandler = SocketHandler('localhost',
                    logging.handlers.DEFAULT_TCP_LOGGING_PORT)
rootLogger.addHandler(socketHandler)
```